# Wp_query post__not_in not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to build a query using wp_query where certain posts id must be excluded. Here is the code that i'm using:

```
$args = array( 'posttype' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 14, 'post__not_in ' => array(71,1), 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'post_status' => 'publish' );
$the_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
```

However wp_query is still returning me the posts with those ID's.

Here is the pastebin with the wp_query object http://pastebin.com/gjayN4Yc.
As for the wp_query->request i'm having the following:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (14,15) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a core bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked fine for me, except there is an extra space after `'post__not_in '`.  Do you see it?  Make sure you have the key as `'post__not_in'`.

Also, there are a couple of things to mention:

1. It's `'post_type'` and not `'posttype`.
2. `'menu_order'` is not available for posts.  That is allocated for hierarchical post types, such as `pages`.  You set that field in the Page Order UI, which is not available (by default) to posts.

Here is the revised code:

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat'            => 14,
    'post__not_in'   => array( 71, 1 ),
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( ! $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    // maybe echo a message that none were found
    return;
}

while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

    // do your business logic here

    // then call the view file to render the HTML
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The SQL query then becomes:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (71,1) AND 
           ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (14) ) AND 
            wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND 
            ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a second underscore after `post` in the `$args` array key - so it's `post__not_in` (2 consecutive underscores) rather than `post_not_in` as per [the WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

Comment: Hello, somehow while pasting it came up wrong but in the source code was just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$aTest = new WP_Query( array( 
                             'post_type'      => 'post', 
                             'posts_per_page' => -1, //all post
                             'order'          => 'ASC',
                             'cat'            => 14,
                             'post__not_in'   => array(27),
                             'orderby'        => 'date',
                             'post_status'    => 'publish'
                             ) );
while ( $aTest ->have_posts() ) : ($aTest ->the_post()) ;
$aTest Image      = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$title            = get_the_title();
$content          = get_the_content();
endwhile;
```